# Displaying PDF in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have LongListSelector with some items in it.When i click on each item i have the selected item value as a string.

```
private void longListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyObject item  =  longListSelector.SelectedItem as MyObject;
            MessageBox.Show(item.ST);
        }
```

The above give me names like Vehicle,Bus.

now in my app i have all the PDF in a folder called PDF with names like Vehicle.pdf,Bus.pdf.

1) How can i display those pdf files ?

2) Will i be able to test the pdf displaying part on emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**MuPDF**](http://www.mupdf.com/)  (a multiplatform lightweight PDF and XPS viewer).

Take a look at this link: [**Reading PDF and XPS on your Windows 8 application using WinRT**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/04/15/reading-pdf-and-xps-on-your-windows-8-application-using-winrt.aspx)